# Simple way to log tapped UI elements / actions in entire project

Tags: ios, logging

I'd like to add make crashlytics reports a bit more useful for my app with list of user actions (similar to what instabug have).

```
2016-12-04 23:16:07.273 Top View: test_instabug.ViewController
2016-12-04 23:16:07.279 Application: DidBecomeActive
2016-12-04 23:16:07.279 Top View: test_instabug.ViewController
2016-12-04 23:16:15.947 Touch: (UIButton) in test_instabug.ViewController
2016-12-04 23:16:15.948 Selector: btnCrashTap: by (UIButton) in test_instabug.ViewController
```

What is the simplest way to log all actions user take in the entire app? I'd like to skip manual implementation of logging for each button / tab / etc, and rather looking for a lib/pod that would intercept user actions for all of them.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Have you tried adding custom keys and logs to your app? https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html

Comment: @MikeBonnell thanks; yes, I'd prefer to have it done automatically for all UI elements (buttons, tabs) rather then deal with each button/tab separately. Added a note for that

Comment: Gotcha, thanks - currently we don't have a built in way to do this. We've chosen to let developers let us know precisely what they want to log or not log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a cocoapod just for that: https://github.com/truemetal/ios-ui-logger

`UILogger is a simple logging framework for UI actions on iOS`